# Get truffle contracts Global Method names

Tags: truffle, ether-pudding

Right now you can access each deployed contract method with Truffle because each is exposed globally.

But I need a way to enumerate each contract say like:

```
 Object.keys(contracts)
```

But since all contracts are in the global namespace, I can't simpy enumerate them through `window`. (Or I'd have to filter it in some way, but that's messy and inefficient).

Any way to get this?

Or if not, what I basically need is get some reference(address) to existing contracts in the chain. (Right now I can see them in truffle output when I deploy a new contract) Can I get the contract's name somehow? Or are you stuck with just an address once you deploy?